# Nightwatch setValue method doesn't work

Tags: javascript, testing, nightwatch.js, e2e-testing

I'm currently trying to set up an Nightwatch project, to see if it's any good. I'm following [This tutorial](https://github.com/dwyl/learn-nightwatch) right now. The stuff from the tutorial works, but when I try to modify it a little bit, it doesn't work anymore. I looked over the [Developer API guide](http://nightwatchjs.org/api), but I guess I'm still missing something? Code I use is pasted below:

```
var conf = require('../../nightwatch.conf.js');

module.exports = {
  'Demo test' : function (browser) {
    browser
      .url('http://localhost/myWebsite?newwindow=0')
      .waitForElementVisible('body', 6000)
      .setValue('input[name=txtLogin]', 'login')
      .setValue('input[name=txtPassword]', 'password')
      .waitForElementVisible('input.btnLogin', 2000)
      .click('button[id=btnLogin]')
      .pause(6000)
      .assert.elementPresent("#selectTitle")
      .assert.containsText('#selectTitle', 'schedules')
      .assert.urlContains('login/login_start.asp')
      .saveScreenshot(conf.imgpath(browser) + 'titleScreen.png')
      .end();

  }
};
```

Error in cmd:

```
Running:  Demo test 
 √ Element <body> was visible after 41 milliseconds.
ERROR: Unable to locate element: "input[name=txtLogin]" using: css selector
at Object.Demo test (C:\Workspace\myWebsite\learn-nightwatch\test\e2e\My_Test.js:8:8)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
ERROR: Unable to locate element: "input[name=txtPassword]" using: css selector
at Object.Demo test (C:\Workspace\myWebsite\learn-nightwatch\test\e2e\My_Test.js:9:8)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
 × Timed out while waiting for element <input.btnLogin> to be present for 2000 milliseconds.  - expected "visible" but got: "not found"
at Object.Demo test (C:\Workspace\myWebsite\learn-nightwatch\test\e2e\My_Test.js:10:8)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
```

And finally, html just to be complete:

```
<input type="text" class="inputText" id="txtLogin" name="txtLogin" >

<input type="password" class="inputText" id="txtPassword"  name="txtPassword" >
```

Answer (score 2):

The `setValue` is tricky for me as well. Sometimes it puts the values but then clears them and currently *(10/10/2017)* out of nowhere it started opening the Chrome Settings tab every time I use the `setValue` function.

What I do now, is first define a function like that

```
var setValue =  function(sel, value) {
    $(sel).val(value).change();
};
```

Then call it from the Nightwatch chain functions like that

```
browser.url('https://google.com')
  .execute(setValue, ['#search', 'keyword'])
  .click('#search-btn')
  .waitForElementVisible('an example of selector')
  .assert.containsText('selector', '100000xxxx results')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to   `.waitForElementVisible('input[name=txtLogin]',6000)` before setValue. IT fixed all my problems. `<body>` will appear immidietly and `input[name=txtLogin]` will need some time to appear.

@EDIT:

```
var conf = require('../../nightwatch.conf.js');

module.exports = {
  'Demo test' : function (browser) {
    browser
      .url('http://localhost/myWebsite?newwindow=0')
      .waitForElementVisible('body', 6000)
      .waitForElementVisible('input[name="txtLogin"]', 6000)
      .setValue('input[name="txtLogin"]', 'login')
      .setValue('input[name="txtPassword"]', 'password')
      .waitForElementVisible('input.btnLogin', 2000)
      .click('button[id="btnLogin"]')
      .assert.elementPresent("#selectTitle")
      .assert.containsText('#selectTitle', 'schedules')
      .assert.urlContains('login/login_start.asp')
      .saveScreenshot(conf.imgpath(browser) + 'titleScreen.png')
      .end();

  }
};
```

Try like above just copy/paste

Comment: Mmhm, I've just tried that, but it still said it cannot find the textbox.    `Timed out while waiting for element <input[name=txtLogin]> to be present for 6000 milliseconds.  - expected "visible" but got: "not found"`

Comment: are you sure that locator is valid ? try `input[type="text"]` or `input[id="txtLogin"]` or `input[name="txtLogin"]` the `""` between are required

Comment: No, none of those work. I can see Nightwatch opening a window and I see the textbox it looks for, but still it can't find it.

Comment: can u post cmd output ? Pause is not required(it can mess tests)

Comment: I'm fairly sure it doesn't reach the pause. This is the pastebin of the cmd output: http://pastebin.com/e6TE9kEQ Using `input[id="txtLogin"]`

Comment: `.assert.title('ur title')` add this after `.waitForElementVisible('body', 6000)` maybe the page isn't loaded fully, sometimes the wierd solutions fix everything

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129906/discussion-between-hikaryu-and-gillesdv).

Answer (score 0):

I was having problems with this and ended up going back to a test script that had worked to confirm that it wasn't me.

There appears to be a problem with setValue and the Selenium drivers https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/issues/1147

My work around was to use the .execute function and update the form fields with jQuery or vanilla javascript.

```
.execute(function(){document.getElementById('_EmailAddress').value = 'email@address.co.uk';})
.execute(function(){$('#_Password').val('PasswordString');})
```